# Entropy change between two systems

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy

Example 14.2 of Concepts in Thermal Phyiscs, 2nd ed:

"Consider two systems, with pressures $p_1$ and $p_2$ and tempreatures $T_1$ and $T_2$. If internal energy $\Delta U$ is trasferred from system 1 to system 2, and volume $\Delta V$ is transferred from system 1 to system 2, find the change of entropy. Show that equilibrium results when $T_1 = T_2$ and $p_1 = p_2$."

The given solution is to use the first law of thermodynamics, $dU = TdS - pdV$, and rewrite it as $dS = (1/T)dU + (p/T)dV$. Then the change in total entropy $\Delta S = \Delta S_1 + \Delta S_2$, is "straightforwardly":

$\Delta S = (1/T_1 - 1/T_2) \Delta U + (p_1/T_1 - p_2/T_2) \Delta V$.

<strike>So if $dz = (1/y)dx$ then $z_2 - z_1 = \int dz = \int (1/y)dx = (1/y_2 - 1/y_1)(x_2 - x_1)$. Why? The last step is not at all straightforward to me. Certainly it's not true in general.</strike> Nevermind, I confused the meaning of indexes 1 and 2; they denote systems 1 and 2, not "before and after".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$dS = (1/T)dU + (p/T)dV$$

for system 1, $$\triangle S_1 = \int 1/T_1d U + \int p_1/T_1dV= 1/T_1 \triangle U + p_1/T_1 \triangle V$$

for system 2, $$\triangle S_2 = -1/T_2 \triangle U - p_2/T_2 \triangle V$$

Thus, the change of the total entropy $$\triangle S = \triangle S_1 + \triangle S_2= (1/T_1 - 1/T_2) \Delta U + (p_1/T_1 - p_2/T_2) \Delta V$$

No entropy change when they are in equilibrium.

Comment: Your answer is correct except that it applies for infinitesimal changes, i.e. integral is not required ($\Delta$ ought to be interpreted as an infinitesimal change). For finite changes (which is given by the integral) you cannot pull out $1/T_1$ and $p_1/T_1$ out of the integral because they are not constant over a finite process.

Comment: I see; I appear to have confused the meanings of index 1 and 2 as "before and after" rather than "systems 1 and 2". However, $dU$ in the first law denotes the energy change of the system, and $\int dU$ should be positive for a positive change, so why are the minus signs on $\Delta S_2$ rather than on $\Delta S_1$? (Also, you appear to have accidentally put some wrong indexes in the $\Delta S_2$ formula.)

Comment: By the way, as @Deep said, isn't this an invalid method for finding $\Delta S$, considering $\Delta U$ and $\Delta V$ are not said to be infinitesimal?

Comment: @Deep , if you can keep $T_1$, $p_1$, $T_2$, $p_2$ constant, the process is not necessary to be infinitesimal.

Comment: @Blrp $\triangle U$ can be positive or negative. We don't have to use sign to indicate that. As the problem said it is taken out from system 1. So its value is negative.

Comment: @user115350 If you keep $T_1,p_1,T_2,p_2,$ constant then there cannot be a process at all.

Comment: @Blrp You must interpret $\Delta$ here as meaning infinitesimal change. Another way to look at it: a finite change $\Delta S$ can be expanded in powers of $\Delta U$ and $\Delta V$ (Taylor series) but in the equations only terms of first order in $\Delta U,\Delta V,$ are considered while higher powers are neglected as being small.

Comment: @user115350 If internal energy 1J is transferred from system 1 to system 2, then $\Delta U = 1J$. Then $\Delta S_1$ due to this change should be $-1J/T_1 = -\Delta U/T_1$, not $1J/T_1 = \Delta U/T_1$. The sign is wrong. If they wanted the interpretation to be $\Delta U = -1J$, they should have said "If internal energy $-\Delta U$ is transferred from system 1 to system 2...", or "If internal energy $\Delta U$ is transferred from system 2 to system 1...". Anyway, that's the book's problem so I'll go ahead and accept the answer.

Comment: @Deep Yes but the stated task was to find $\Delta S$ given changes $\Delta U$ and $\Delta V$ which were not stated to be infinitesimal, so the solution the book gave is wrong (or the question is).